# Long polling with GMail API

Tags: python, imap, long-polling, gmail-api

I'm building an installation that will run for several days and needs to get notifications from a GMail inbox in real time. The Gmail API is great for many of the features I need, so I'd like to use it. However, it has no IDLE command like IMAP.

Right now I've created a GMail API implementation that polls the mailbox every couple of seconds. This works great, but times out after a while (I get "connection reset by peer"). So, is it reasonable to turn off the sesson and restart it every half an hour or so to keep it active (like with IDLE)? Is that a terrible, terrible hack that will have google busting down my door in the middle of the night?

Would the proper solution be to log in with IMAP as well and use IDLE to notify my GMail API module to start up and pull in changes when they occur? Or should I just suck it up and create an IMAP only implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would definitely recommend against IMAP, note that even with the IMAP IDLE command it isn't real time--it's just polling every few (5?) seconds under the covers and then pushing out to the connection.  (Experiment yourself and see the delay there.)

Querying history.list() frequently is quite cheap and should be fine.  If this is for a sizeable number of users you may want to do a little bit of optimization like intelligent backoff for inactive mailboxes (e.g. every time there's no updates backoff by an extra 5s up to some maximum like a minute or two)?

Google will definitely not bust down your door or likely even notice unless you're doing it every second with 1M users.  :)

Real push notifications for the API is definitely something that's called for.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I'm doing! I'm very interested to hear that IDLE isn't a true push either.

It seems like the "connection reset by peer" option might just be the host computer going to sleep. More testing is needed.

Comment: Curiously, do I need to breakdown/rebuild the monitor every few minutes, like in IMAP IDLE? Is there any reason?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, can you clarify/restate?

Comment: Oh sorry. With IMAP a server timeout, "[typically occurs after 30 minutes with no activity](http://www.isode.com/whitepapers/imap-idle.html)." That article recommends sending a "no operations" command (NOOP) every 15 minutes or so to keep it open. Elsewhere I've read that the connection should be shut down and restarted. What would the equivalent here be? Do I even need to worry? This will run for several days and I do not want it timing out overnight with no activity.

Comment: IMAP is a single connection hence the tcp timeouts with the server and proxies come into play forcing the need for keepalives.  Not the same with HTTP connections.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting connection reset by peer because you are exceeding Google quota. Every GMail API request has quota defined [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota).